# Allow safe FTP upload

Tags: .htaccess, ftp

I'd like to allow my friend to upload some photos for me over FTP to my server (shared host). It's a trusted friend but I'd still like to block the execution of any php or similar scripts etc.

How can I use .htaccess (in a directory above the one I allow FTP to acces) to block everything except a list of approved extensions (images) and disallow htaccess (to prevent any further modifications)?

Does such method still have security risks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
<FilesMatch ".+">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
    Allow From localhost # OR WHATEVER HERE
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|gif|stuff)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow From All
</FilesMatch>
```

---

**EDIT**

For preventing further modifications to htaccess, you need to set filesystem permissions accordingly (aka OS dependent), since you are most likely to give your friend full FTP access (including delete/overwrite/append).

Comment: @dialer, thanks for your answer. I'm not really sure what do you mean by your edit, how can I use filesystem permissions to disallow overwriting htaccess rules?

Comment: I've tried the code you posted and unfortunately, it doesn't work, I can call and execute php scripts...

Comment: @Czechnology That shouldn't be the case. Are you sure, you aren't calling it from localhost? Also, make sure to try F5 as the browser may just cache the site.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake, I didn't allow htaccess for this subdomain. This works now but it's still not exactly what I'd like. My idea was to put .htaccess file in a `/upload` dir (where everything is allowed) and use it to disable scripts in a subdirectory, e.g. `/upload/user` (which is the root of user's ftp access), and forbid further directives with `AllowOverride None`. This would be easy if `<Directory>` directive was allowed in htaccess but it's not. Is there another option? Slowly I'm thinking that using rewrite engine is the only option here...

Comment: @Czechnology You can't use `<Directory>` in htaccess files, that is correct. You can only use the httpd.conf for you server, if you are allowed to modify that, or as I already stated set filesystem permissions to disallow writing access to the file. As i've stated, this is still OS dependent.

Comment: My system (from phpinfo): `Linux 2.6.18-194.26.1.el5.028stab070.14 #1 SMP Thu Dec 16 14:30:32 CET 2010 i686`, `PHP Version 5.2.17-pl0-gentoo`. I'm not able to modify apache main config (as I've said, it's just a shared host). Anyway, why not simply use RewriteRule to send a F(orbidden) response? Would it somehow be a security risk?

Comment: @Czechnology Giving full FTP access including Write/Delete to a directory which is also accessible through your webserver is generally a security problem. Even if you hide your htaccess in another directory, your FTP user could upload his own htaccess and override all your security measures. To prevent this, you need to deny the ftpd's right to overwrite this specific file. `chmod 744 ".htaccess"` _could_ solve this issue, if the ftpd user doesn't have the right to change it back. However, you must create the file directly on the server, not using FTP, or you have to call `chown` as well.